# How can I install one language by command-line

Tags: 12.04, command-line, language-support

I'm trying to have everything ready to install a new desktop with a few command line instructions.
Unfortunately, to install the language packages, I couldn't find how to do it.

I can run

```
gnome-language-selector
```

But it doesn't seems to be usable in command line directly. I need to go on with clicks...

An other thing that could be done is that I do those clicks and find out which packages have been installed and read the changes in /etc/environment and /etc/default/locale (and other /etc/... file?) but the list of packages is probably different depending on the packages installed (Firefox, Thunderbird, LibreOffice, Gnome, ...)

Is there a tool for that? Like let's say :

```
gnome-language-selector --install fr
```

or a package that has all necessary dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get install super-language-pack-fr
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For desktop you can

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-[cod] language-pack-gnome-[cod] language-pack-[cod]-base language-pack-gnome-[cod]-base
```

But each applications can have its language pack.
To know the packages to be installed try:

```
check-language-support -l [cod]
```

For example:

```
check-language-support -l fr
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't install all that would be installed by gnome-language-selector; in my case : libreoffice-l10n-fr language-pack-gnome-fr language-pack-fr-base hunspell-fr language-pack-gnome-fr-base firefox-locale-fr mythes-fr libreoffice-help-fr hyphen-fr wfrench language-pack-fr thunderbird-locale-fr

Comment: There are no language-support-writing-[cod] package available for 12.04 ... It disappeared with 11.10.

Comment: Edited. Please, check if the last additions are useful...:)

Comment: Excellent! The final command is

sudo apt-get install $(check-language-support -l fr)

Comment: Or `yes | sudo apt-get install \`check-language-support -l fr\``

Comment: How can one find the two-letter code for a given language?

Answer (score 18):

Auto install all dependencies:

```
sudo apt -y install $(check-language-support -l fr)
```

Where `fr` is the desired two-letter (ISO 639-1) language code.

Comment: hint: the `apt-get install` can take the `-y` option. No need to use `yes` and pipe.

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to edit the locale.gen file.

```
sudo vim /etc/locale.gen
```

Then looking for the language pack you need and remove the comment mark, for example, if I want to install zh_CN.GBK GBK zh_CN.UTF8, I just remove the # symbol in these lines, alternatively, you can also add your lines directly into the file.
Finally, run:

```
sudo locale-gen
```

This is the simplest way I found online.

Answer (score 0):

To add french language to Ubuntu using the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Quoted from there:

> This metapackage depends on all packages that provide native language
>   support for applications. (like spell checkers, dictionaries,
>   OpenOffice and Mozilla locale packages, etc.).
>
> If you also want your applications and the desktop to be translated,
>   please additionally install language-pack-fr.

So it may not have the language for certain programs.

---

To add a language to Ubuntu using the Command line:

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get install language-support-fr
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't install all that would be installed by gnome-language-selector; in my case : libreoffice-l10n-fr language-pack-gnome-fr language-pack-fr-base hunspell-fr language-pack-gnome-fr-base firefox-locale-fr mythes-fr libreoffice-help-fr hyphen-fr wfrench language-pack-fr thunderbird-locale-fr