# Do additional language packs need to be downloaded?

Tags: software-installation, language-support

I'm installing Ubuntu (12.04) right now.

I wanted to know if additional language packs have to be downloaded because my Internet is very slow. I chose English as my language.

Comment: No. Language packages does not have to be downloaded during installation. You just have to click the SKIP button on the installation process.

Comment: ..adding to @Peachy's comment above, you can always download and install the packages after system installation which is also a suggested approach if your have a slow internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISO does not contain everything you need, instead it holds most necessary things.

There is a guide to install a language pack [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149876/how-can-i-install-one-language-by-command-line).

Comment: there's a strange thing i noticed that it download the libre office language pack, but i can just open libre office just fine (display language is english). Without the language pack, shouldn't it open at all?

Comment: Duo8, the default language for Libre Office is English-US. If you need a different variant, you can download it.

Answer (score 0):

**In short**: you don't need to install additional language packages. However, spelling, grammar, and punctuation differences between English should be considered before deciding to *not install* additional packages.

Since your main installation language is English, you don't need to worry about additional language packages, unless the application/package is released not in English.

If you can download packages outside of your PC, you can use this script and execute it on Internet cafe's or your friend's PC to obtain additional language packages.

```
sudo apt-get <<<apt-get command and options>>> --print-uris -qq | sed -n "s/'\([^ ]\+\)' \([^ ]\+\) \([^ ]\+\) MD5Sum:\([^ ]\+\)/wget -c \1/p" > script.cmd
```

Question related: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score -1):

I think it's necessary to download. Check [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) to find a nearby server to add in your `etc/apt/source.list`.