# Change keyboard layout inside recovery mode

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout, recovery-mode

I had two keyboard layouts: "Swedish" and "Farsi" in my Ubuntu 11.10. After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 I now am stuck at login screen. Reason is that I only see and have Farsi layout which has close to Arabic words and my password requires latin words.

I am not such a big user of Ubuntu. I wanted to change setting in /etc/default/keyboard however the layout is mentioned to be "se" standing for Swedish however what I see is Farsi layout.

I tried commanding sudo apt-get install console-common, however in recovery mode, I could not get anything.

If your solution requires changing config files in console, please write the command too as I only know "cat" command.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the hotkey for switching keyboard-language (shift+shiftlock) on loginscreen already? If SE is installed it may work.