# Language packages not showing in Language support

Tags: package-management, language-support

In my Ubuntu I went to **System Settings > Language support -> Install/Remove Languages** and I just get English.

I tried `sudo apt-get install language-pack-fr language-pack-gnome-fr language-pack-fr-base language-pack-gnome-fr-base` as suggested in the answer to [How can I install one language by command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149876/how-can-i-install-one-language-by-command-line). For any language I try I get no success with this method.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Weird. I have a [whole huge list of them](https://imgur.com/a/3zp4K). Are you connected to the internet AND do you have the repositories up-to-date?

Comment: Something is definitely off mine show a bunch of them!

Comment: Can you please open Language Support from terminal, i.e. the command `gnome-language-selector`, and click the "Install / Remove Languages..." button. Please show us - by editing your question - any messages which appeared in terminal.

Comment: Close voters. HowTo answer completed...

Comment: @ElderGeek: Hmm.. The OP's problem, if I understand it correctly, is that only English is visible in the _Installed Languages_ window.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Clearly I need more sleep. Updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the root cause of this issue is that /usr/share/language-selector/data/languagelist is missing or incomplete. This file can be found in the package [language-selector-common](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/language-selector-common). A quick peek at `dpkg -l *language-selector*` shows that the following should have been installed by default.

```
ii  language-selector-common    0.165.4            all                Language selector for Ubuntu
ii  language-selector-gnome     0.165.4            all                Language selector for Ubuntu
```

`sudo apt install --reinstall language-selector-common` will likely do the trick. If not you may need to purge and then reinstall with

`sudo apt-get purge language-selector-common` be aware that this approach will remove both language-selector-common and language-selector-gnome  so we have to reinstall both of them with

`sudo apt-get install language-selector-common language-selector-gnome`

Open Language support from the dash:

[image: langsupport]

Click install/remove languages.

[image]

Scroll to the language you wish to install, tick the box and click apply changes.

[image]

Support for your chosen language will be installed:

Note that:

[image]

Now that you've installed the language in your system, each user (this means you) can select it as an option in text entry settings as shown below:

[image: text entry]

Hit the <kbd>+</kbd> button to bring up the menu as shown below:

[image: AddFrench]

Now you can select French as a text entry language.

[image: SelectFrench]

You may wish to also check the keyboard layout chart.

**Tested on Ubuntu 16.04**