# Language and Regional Support Compromised

Tags: 18.04, updates, language-support

I am updating to Ubuntu 18.04. I looked at [this question,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961124/language-packages-not-showing-in-language-support) but that doesn't fix my problem. I have only EN showing, although I have 5 languages installed. 
I have only default regional settings but I cannot change any 
[language settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTFWc.png), [installed languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W53XG.png), or [regional support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsQWl.png). 
I think the update has messed up. How can I repair this?

Comment: Try: `sudo apt install --reinstall language-selector-*`

Comment: thank you   some improvement was noticable but the problem isn't solved 
the installed languages are not displayed, in cannot modify the regional setting for dates, decimals etc

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us what the terminal commands `locale` and `locale -a` output.

Comment: dxxxk@Axxxxger:~$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
dxxxk@Axxxxger:~$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_GB.utf8
POSIX

Comment: You have screwed up your locale somehow. Try to generate the locales with this command: `sudo locale-gen`

Comment: Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  -...-
  nl_NL.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
Generation complete.
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
$ locale -a
-...-  long list cut -..- 
nl_NL.utf8
POSIX

Comment: I now have a list of languages, and the correct regioanl setting